# My bluetooth keyboard needs re-pairing every time I boot into Linux Mint

Tags: keyboard, linux-mint, bluetooth

I have a Keychron K4 keyboard and a Logitech MX Master 3 mouse, both interacting directly with the onboard bluetooth (i.e. not with a dongle or adapter). Whenever I (re)boot or wake from suspension, the mouse reconnects to bluetooth no problem. But the keyboard is completely disconnected and will not reconnect unless I pair them all over again. I'm fairly new to Linux.

Answer (score 2):

The article
[How to fix “Bluetooth device doesn’t auto-connect” in Linux](https://techwiser.com/fix-bluetooth-device-doesnt-auto-connect-in-linux/)
has this advice:

- Ensure that the file `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` contains the line
  `AutoEnable=true`, and if not then append it at the end
- Make the device be trusted with the command
  `bluetoothctl trust mac_address`, where `mac_address` is the MAC address
  of the device
- Remove the Bluetooth device and pair it back again
- Reinstall Bluetooth with the command `sudo apt reinstall bluez`
- If all failed, download the
  [bluetooth-autoconnect script](https://github.com/jrouleau/bluetooth-autoconnect)
  and move the service and scripts to their respective location,
  to automatically connect to all paired and trusted Bluetooth devices.

You will find more details and screenshots in the linked article.